# Center users location on Google maps but allow free movement

Tags: android, google-maps

I have created my first app that shows a users location information along with the location shown on google maps. Currently the app/map works perfectly as I want it to apart from one **little niggle and that the map keeps jumping back to users location and zooms back to the set value**.

What I am after is the map to update the users location and zoom into it but only do this when it connects to the GPS. Once it has done this and the user has moved the map about or zoomed in and out the location is still shown but it is not centered again and or zoomed back in/out (every time location is changed), similar to how Google Maps app does it.

Currently I have the following code in the `onLocationChanged` method and I'm sure that I need to move this or create some logic to do what I'm after.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

// Update Location On Map
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0F));
}
```

This is using the latest `GoogleAPIClient`. I have looked at a lot of the tutorials on here and the net and I cant seem to figure it out. I'm sure it will be simple fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a boolean flag and set it true after once map has zoomed at the user location

```
boolean isFirstLocation=false;
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    // Set user marker on the map on every location change with this code
      LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
      MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(currentLatLng);
      mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    // Update Location On Map
      if(!isFirstLocation)
    {
      mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng , 16.0F));
     isFirstLocation=true;
    }

}
```

No need to animate Camera on every location change

Answer (score 0):

```
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }
```

if your Position is changed then this will automatic focus and change marker to your current position..
hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this is the example i used to start with. This work fine apart from it keeps updating the location and centering the location. What im after is for it to do this on when it connects then allow the map free movement without re centering.